# Disable hardware backbuttton in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to disable the hardware backbutton on the phone for just this  one particular fragment.

fragment:

```
public class Second_frag extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    String RSSFEEDURL = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/TwitterRssFeedXML?format=xml";
    RSSFeed feed;
    String fileName;

    View myView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash,container,false);
         ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();


        fileName = "Feed.td";

        File feedFile = getActivity().getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName);

        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {

            // No connectivity. Check if feed File exists
            if (!feedFile.exists()) {

                // No connectivity & Feed file doesn't exist: Show alert to exit
                // & check for connectivity
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage(
                        "Unable to reach server, \nPlease check your connectivity.")
                        .setTitle("TD RSS Reader")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Exit",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                        getActivity().finish();
                                    }
                                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {

                // No connectivty and file exists: Read feed from the File
                Toast.makeText(Second_frag.this.getActivity(), "No connectivity. Reading last update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                feed = ReadFeed(fileName);
                startLisActivity(feed);
            }

        } else {

            // Connected - Start parsing
            new AsyncLoadXMLFeed().execute();

        }
        return myView;


    }

    private void startLisActivity(RSSFeed feed) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);
        List_Activity fragment = new List_Activity();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.workdarnit, fragment).commit();


    }

    private class AsyncLoadXMLFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Obtain feed
            DOMParser myParser = new DOMParser();
            feed = myParser.parseXml(RSSFEEDURL);
            if (feed != null && feed.getItemCount() > 0)
                WriteFeed(feed);
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            startLisActivity(feed);
        }

    }

    // Method to write the feed to the File
    private void WriteFeed(RSSFeed data) {

        FileOutputStream fOut =null ;
        ObjectOutputStream osw = null;

        try {
            fOut = getActivity().openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            osw = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
            osw.writeObject(data);
            osw.flush();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                if(fOut !=null){
                    fOut.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // Method to read the feed from the File
    private RSSFeed ReadFeed(String fName) {

        FileInputStream fIn = null;
        ObjectInputStream isr = null;

        RSSFeed _feed = null;
        File feedFile = getActivity().getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName);
        if (!feedFile.exists())
            return null;

        try {
            fIn = getActivity().openFileInput(fName);
            isr = new ObjectInputStream(fIn);

            _feed = (RSSFeed) isr.readObject();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                if(fIn !=null){
                    fIn.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return _feed;

    }



    }
```

I tried adding `onbackpress`on the fragment but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {


        Fragment myFragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                myFragment = new home();
                break;
            case 1:
                myFragment = new First_frag();
                break;
            case 2:
                myFragment = new Second_frag();
                break;
            case 3:
                myFragment = new Third_frag();
                break;
            case 4:
                myFragment = new First_frag_o();
                break;
            case 5:
                myFragment = new QuizF();
                break;
            case 6:
                myFragment = new Surv_list();
                break;
        }

        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, myFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
            case 4:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
                break;
            case 5:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
                break;
            case 6:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section6);
                break;
            case 7:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section7);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));

        }


    }



}
```

Comment: what do u want the backpressed to do when in fragment

Comment: nothing. I need it to be disabled when that particular fragment is opened

Comment: `onBackPressed()` belongs to the Activity, not to the Fragment.

Comment: ok..the i intialize a variable true when that particular fragment is called..n in onBackpressed method check the condition..if variable true do nothing if false call super.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle this in the Activity in the onBackPressed() method. 
In the method you look for your fragment, and if visible, do nothing.

If the frament is not visible, simply call super.onBackPressed().

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick:

```
Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

Boolean isSecFragmnet=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {


        Fragment myFragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                myFragment = new home();
isSecFragmnet=false;
                break;
            case 1:
                myFragment = new First_frag();
isSecFragmnet=false;
                break;
            case 2:
                myFragment = new Second_frag();
isSecFragmnet=true;
                break;
            case 3:
                myFragment = new Third_frag();
isSecFragmnet=false;
                break;
            case 4:
                myFragment = new First_frag_o();
isSecFragmnet=false;
                break;
            case 5:
                myFragment = new QuizF();
isSecFragmnet=false;
                break;
            case 6:
                myFragment = new Surv_list();
isSecFragmnet=false;
                break;
        }

        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, myFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
            case 4:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
                break;
            case 5:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
                break;
            case 6:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section6);
                break;
            case 7:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section7);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));

        }


    }

 @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {


                if (isSecFragment) {
                    //do nothing
                    Log.e("backpressed", "pressed");
                } else

               {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is isFragment? Is it where I put Second_frag?

Comment: in ur code the where u r calling ur Second_frag initilaize a bolean variable true

Comment: show me ur code where u r calling ur fragment i can help u better

Comment: I've added the `MainActivity`

Comment: declare this  isSecFrag=false;   switch (position) {
            case 0:
                myFragment = new home();
                break;
            case 1:
                myFragment = new First_frag();
                break;
            case 2:
                myFragment = new Second_frag();  isSecFrag=true;
                break;   and in rest of the cases and the places u r calling fragmets initialize it as false. and write the method described above in ur Mainactivity...i hope u get it

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment currFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (currFrag instanceof Second_frag) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

or if you rather want fragment to decide if it will enable back button, than all fragments would like to extend common `TemplateFragment`:

```
public class TemplateFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    public boolean enableOnBackPressed() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Second_frag extends TemplateFragment {
    ...

    @Override
    public final boolean enableOnBackPressed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this in activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment currFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (currFrag instanceof TemplateFragment) {
        if (!((TemplateFragment) currFrag).enableOnBackPressed()) {
            //do nothing
            return;
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: This is the proper approach but findFragmentById() may return the Fragment even if not visible (ie if covered by another fragment on the same container or on another container). Probably better to do findFragmentByTag(), this way you dont have to check for instanceOf,  then check for visibility.

Comment: The first one works but the problem is that the back button doesn't work on the `List_Activity` fragment that is initiated after `Second_frag`